# how to select simulator version

Tags: ios, reactjs, ios-simulator, native

I am not able to run react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone Xs', my system comes back with could not find iPhone xs simulator.

I can run the application in Xcode, but just not the command line.  When I run xcrun simctl list --json devices, I am getting the following.  I believe react-native run-ios is looking at com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1, how do I make it use com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2?

```
{
  "devices" : {
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-1" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "Apple TV",
        "udid" : "47D6637C-8977-40BF-A2D7-68051745EAAF",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
        "udid" : "625F2E70-54B4-49EE-ABB8-9D8FC584A75A",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
        "udid" : "A3895E78-0012-467E-8410-7336FFA6FDCB",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      }
    ],
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "B9CDC3FE-6B62-4631-A401-A7422DBAD522",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 6",
        "udid" : "CB0701A9-C302-47A7-A954-D25FD1B4742F",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
        "udid" : "3D4DFC22-D17D-41B7-B33B-35F524E030C2",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 6s",
        "udid" : "C7EA34AA-2833-437A-A529-3E0FBB8B0BDC",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
        "udid" : "F3CF757B-7180-401F-8CF7-14B10F51E5D8",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 7",
        "udid" : "6A788EF6-EB57-449B-AA36-8CDE05291821",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
        "udid" : "6EF5A064-158B-4C4E-A5B4-38FCA3FA55B6",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 8",
        "udid" : "509D9F43-663B-479F-9303-7F6FB27F99C8",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
        "udid" : "F9516AB1-A74C-4030-A625-4DDD040C6E3C",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone SE",
        "udid" : "7696054C-341A-46AA-BDCF-10711C6E5EE1",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone X",
        "udid" : "EEA96931-5FA7-4F38-89F1-33BFF1C50177",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone XS",
        "udid" : "93FDF5AB-7C1E-413F-ABC6-C2CD978E91C3",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone XS Max",
        "udid" : "3AC55A7C-1DD5-40BC-A921-802920E057F3",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
        "name" : "iPhone XR",
        "udid" : "F5A27B1F-B050-4626-8686-EC3694573505",
        "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Air",
    "udid" : "C792B237-2EF0-484C-9A3B-CD1803B9FB4B",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Air 2",
    "udid" : "D8967DC2-187D-424B-BAAB-020E6EEBCDEA",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
    "udid" : "77C6DE6F-8C47-4A14-AA2A-66AB07E12FE7",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
    "udid" : "C8931B84-BBB7-456C-8984-ECEBA19D30A2",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
    "udid" : "FBF8FC5F-7D99-4FE0-9D12-B39902EC8032",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
    "udid" : "A7A5F5EB-2885-4639-9AD6-2E2B051AF246",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
    "udid" : "80A2441D-693B-4310-BB93-88D9801409C0",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad (6th generation)",
    "udid" : "2203481A-C2DC-4BAA-A98F-F66E1626E3E8",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
    "udid" : "38052D09-F270-409A-A6E4-6FF2F03CC5BC",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
    "udid" : "3073A145-F87A-4C21-8238-9F2A162A898B",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  }
],
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-2" : [
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple TV",
    "udid" : "C10B2AE1-AC15-49A9-8A83-823B8BA6C2A7",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
    "udid" : "4AB3B3DC-1982-4A75-97B8-9C536BCEE9EB",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
    "udid" : "AD877911-B88E-426E-B1C5-C1B9CE24ACDA",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  }
],
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-5-2" : [
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
    "udid" : "822BE09B-2D91-4361-ADC8-A0DC071BB392",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
    "udid" : "919A9BD5-673E-4B2F-A008-F8FB34B5F8A4",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
    "udid" : "F82AE6DB-D9D9-4AE4-9B24-EE3AF7088A8A",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
    "udid" : "13BE6A87-59F6-4ED3-B79A-64C5015AEFE2",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm",
    "udid" : "5E1CD222-4B96-4800-8394-5502A8683C75",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm",
    "udid" : "021D9046-B459-4009-8CE1-877D8F8A416E",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  }
],
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-5-1" : [
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
    "udid" : "6B409A70-5774-4421-B683-6CEEF3AE73B2",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
    "udid" : "DBE3A5AB-E2EC-421A-B2CA-8A2AE1C70211",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
    "udid" : "A4C36D9A-6A5F-474E-9530-4F95B4C643CB",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
    "udid" : "B90D3E1F-63C7-4C97-AEB9-284AFBFFB5E9",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm",
    "udid" : "57BF8CC4-69A0-485B-B2C5-A187FBD5FE74",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(unavailable, runtime profile not found)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : false,
    "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm",
    "udid" : "945D0EFA-9E58-47C9-9D7F-DF8B6D55AA67",
    "availabilityError" : "runtime profile not found"
  }
],
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2" : [
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 5s",
    "udid" : "B537333A-E0E9-4DA5-81C2-9994936859CA",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 6",
    "udid" : "66B462FD-5A5C-4BDA-8CAC-50C8B3B3F6D5",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
    "udid" : "9AAC9BC1-3F41-42CD-94F1-ED6CE4C4794D",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 6s",
    "udid" : "934378C2-8870-4BB3-AE6A-C831AB5CD2C9",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
    "udid" : "08556E9F-EAB2-4FE5-8E22-C29B2EDBE9AA",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 7",
    "udid" : "6F204673-2CCC-40C9-B6E1-735B3B754431",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
    "udid" : "736481BA-AA78-40B7-86C1-A278E1B13890",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 8",
    "udid" : "48142B50-AA6C-4863-811E-1733108A04DE",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
    "udid" : "EBEBE3A2-0E7D-46F1-B2D5-4C2A448AB90E",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone SE",
    "udid" : "6E3000BB-B27E-4D8D-AAAC-4885F39B1D16",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone X",
    "udid" : "B19AF730-A284-4D85-B4D1-5C5BE2556907",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone Xs",
    "udid" : "94015246-E696-4B58-A93D-46234AC8CDA9",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone Xs Max",
    "udid" : "1FA53F89-B3C9-489D-AB7B-677621E76DD6",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone Xʀ",
    "udid" : "FB1220B4-A098-462E-A774-A97E88FAD5BC",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Air (3rd generation)",
    "udid" : "EB203594-043F-4866-AD08-F2E06BC8A627",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Air",
    "udid" : "D5C6DAD5-4827-496E-AD6F-230209068F90",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Air 2",
    "udid" : "B0F40970-5A40-4309-833E-D61DBB2C35D2",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
    "udid" : "6B3513EE-6292-4574-A9F8-027E3D3FFE2E",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
    "udid" : "E7CF80AC-12F3-45C6-B5CC-F44A1DDDC694",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
    "udid" : "09E2B825-4848-43E2-9A3E-AA5FD7AFA09A",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
    "udid" : "161100D0-50D1-4E87-B20D-B5CFF2DD61ED",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
    "udid" : "36030EA4-2D6E-4C41-88BE-982A40FDE6E2",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad (6th generation)",
    "udid" : "41103DF3-146C-4C8A-8FC9-299AD7B3F199",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
    "udid" : "AF7E1372-1EB5-4F9D-B2CE-E708A00C7C7A",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  },
  {
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
    "udid" : "19B3808D-0141-404C-9A86-ED3D29600C20",
    "availabilityError" : ""
  }
    ]
  }
}
```